Issue with Extracting "trace_id" from Logs in Elasticsearch Using Filebeat Pipeline
I am currently pushing logs to the Elasticsearch from Filebeat. I’m trying to extract the trace_id from the message field and store the value in a separate field.
The message field has the value:
2024-09-23 10:00:915 [http-nio-9100-exec-1] [INFO ] com.ZZZ.YYY.service.UserService [XXXX-80c4-437c-b7ae-XXXXX,YYYYYY-4e90-474e-ba30-YYYYY] [ZZZ-services,post/MMM/process] : Getting user by uuid <getUserByUUID>YYYYYY-4e90-474e-ba30-YYYYY
I created an ingest pipeline with a Grok pattern to capture the trace_id, but it doesn’t appear in Kibana. I have added the pipeline name in the filebeat configuration as well.
Grok pattern: %{YEAR:year}-%{MONTHNUM:month}-%{MONTHDAY:day} %{HOUR:hour}:%{MINUTE:minute}:%{NUMBER:milliseconds} \[%{DATA:thread}\] \[%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}\s\] %{JAVACLASS:class} \[%{UUID:trace_id},%{UUID:other_id}\] \[%{DATA:service}\] : %{GREEDYDATA:message}
When I tested the ingest pipeline using a document, it was able to extract is successfully.
My question is why is the trace_id field not appearing in Kibana?
Is there any additional configurations to be done?
